# Layout mobile "quebrando" no firefox

Tags: suporte, bug, status-pronto, layout, mobile

Ao acessar a versão mobile do SO usando o navegador firefox, notei que o layout apresenta alguns problemas, como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que está "vazando" para o lado direito, algumas perguntas nem são totalmente visíveis quando o texto se alonga a direita, por causa desse "vazamento".

Além disso, alguns códigos longos horizontalmente, que forçam o scroll horizontal no site full, não ocorre na versão mobile, enquanto usando o firefox.

O print é da resposta [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114217/select-para-ordenar-por-hora).

Obs.: Somente no firefox é que isso ocorre, no Chrome o funcionamento é normal, tanto pro scroll horizontal dos códigos, quanto ao "vazamento" do layout, que não ocorre.

Comment: Notei em outros dispositivos e navegadores também, as vezes o `overflow: auto` não funciona.

Answer (score 5):

Tenho problemas parecidos nos navegadores padrões do Windows 10 Mobile e Windows Phone 8.1. E não ocorre apenas no site do SOpt, é em todos os sites da rede quando acessados na versão mobile.

Acho que o jeito é usar o app mesmo, se você tiver Android ou iOS. (Usando W10 Mobile ou WP 8.1? O jeito é continuar sofrendo.)

E uma coisa que tenho dúvida, será que adianta reportar esse bug aqui no meta do SOpt? Será que isso irá chegar aos ouvidos do pessoal do Stack Exchange? Porque né... está em Português...

Comment: Costuma adiantar sim

Comment: Não vai receber a mesma visibilidade, mas adiante porque tem brasileiros e portugueses trabalhando lá, além de gringos que falam português. Eu mesmo conversei com um no TDC do ano passado.

Comment: Legal! Bom saber!